# Locust/Python and using values from one list in another list

Tags: python, locust

I have list 1:

```
TS_IDs = [
    '10158',
    '10159',
    '10174'
]
```

and list 2:

```
values = [
    {
        "id": 10017,
        "values": [
            {
                "from": "2022-10-30T12:00:00Z",
                "to": "2022-10-30T13:00:00Z",
                "value": 15
            },
            {
                "from": "2022-10-30T13:00:00Z",
                "to": "2022-10-30T14:00:00Z",
                "value": 16
            }
      ]
    }
]
```

I want to use values from list 1 into list 2 for the id-value (here being 10017).

How can that be obtained?

Comment: What resulting data are you looking for?

Comment: You want the items from `values` that match a value in `TS_IDs `?

Comment: For every call I make I want the "values" payload/list2 to include a different value from the list1 for the ID field, everything else being static.

so I thought maybe like:

values = [
    {
        "id": random.Random(TS_IDs),
        "values": [
            {
                "from": "2022-10-30T12:00:00Z",
                "to": "2022-10-30T13:00:00Z",
                "value": 15
            },
            {
                "from": "2022-10-30T13:00:00Z",
                "to": "2022-10-30T14:00:00Z",
                "value": 16
            },

Comment: Why are you using random? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76581380/edit) your question with a minimal/reproducable example

Comment: Not imortant to use random, just unique values for every call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely looking for `random.choice()` assuming you want to assign a randomly selected item from `TS_IDs` to each item in `values`.

```py
import random
import copy

## ---------------------------
## Just so we don't mutate values
## ---------------------------
values_new = copy.deepcopy(values)
## ---------------------------

for item in values_new:
    item["id"] = random.choice(TS_IDs)

print(values_new)
```

However, if you want to assign the ids randomly without duplication (assuming the length of `values` is less than the length of `TS_IDs`) you might use `random.sample()` or `random.shuffle()` on `TS_IDs`.

```py
import random
import copy

## ----------------------
## get a random ordering of TS_IDs.
## random.sample() works as well but mutates TS_IDs
## ----------------------
TS_IDs_new = random.sample(TS_IDs, len(TS_IDs))
## ----------------------

## ---------------------------
## Just so we don't mutate values
## ---------------------------
values_new = copy.deepcopy(values)
## ---------------------------

for index, item in enumerate(values_new):
    item["id"] = TS_IDs_new[index]

print(values_new)
```

If you want to just use `TS_IDs` in order then:

```py
import random
import copy

## ---------------------------
## Just so we don't mutate values
## ---------------------------
values_new = copy.deepcopy(values)
## ---------------------------

for index, item in enumerate(values_new):
    item["id"] = TS_IDs[index]

print(values_new)
```

Note, you might want to place a guard against `values` having more items than `TS_IDs` in the last two cases.